# A simple linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a list of real numbers $x_k$, $k=1,\dots, N$ where $x_k\neq 0 $ $\forall$ $k$ and $\sum\limits_k x_k = 1$. I have two other list of real numbers $\alpha_k$, $\beta_k$ s.t. $0\leq \alpha_k, \beta_k \leq 1$. The following statements are true 
$$\sum\limits_k x_k \alpha_k = 1  $$ $$\sum\limits_k x_k \beta_k =1$$ $$\sum\limits_k x_k \alpha_k \beta_k =1 $$ is it true that either $\alpha_k = 1$ $\forall$ $k$ or  $\beta_k = 1$ $\forall$ $k$? And if so, how do I prove this?. In other words, I have the vectors $x$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ with the above properties, and $x\cdot \alpha =1$, $x\cdot \beta = 1$ and $x\cdot (\alpha \circ \beta) = 1$, where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. What conditions if any imply that $\alpha$ or $\beta$ are a vector of ones - are the above conditions sufficient?

Comment: Do you really mean $\alpha+\beta$ in your last line?

Comment: sorry i took this out, i meant the Hadamard product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be reformulated in the following way. Given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whose entries are not all $1$, does the system of linear equations
$$ \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\ 
           \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \dots & \alpha_N \\
          \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \dots & \beta_N   \\
          \alpha_1 \beta_1 & \alpha_2 \beta_2 & \dots & \alpha_N \beta_N
          \end{matrix}\right) \cdot x = \left( \begin{matrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{matrix} \right) $$
have a solution?

There are many examples where this is the case for example, if $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_4$ are all distinct and $\beta_i = \alpha_i^2$ for $i = 1, \dots, 4$, then the above matrix contains a $4 \times 4$ submatrix which is invertible being (the transpose of) a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: what is the top row of 1's in the matrix for?

Comment: It is for your assumption on $x$ that $\sum_k x_k  = 1$.